# Get Laravel Mix to transpile JS from different path

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel Mix, and it nicely simplifies using WebPack & Babel to transpile advance JS features down to older browsers - EXCEPT! (and I'm going crazy here) ... it only works for me if I put the JS to be transpiled into the directory they recommend.

The basic recommended "webpack.mix.js" setup is `mix.js(['resources/js/app.js'], 'public/js/app.js');`
where the first argument can be a single file or an array of files to be transpiled.

The default `resources/js/app.js` requires several standard modules, like vue, lodash, axios. Works great. Then in `app.js` I want to require some additional sources from `vendor/xxxx/assets/js/xx.js` - but I get an error: **`Unknown plugin "transform-object-rest-spread" specified`** - which means it can't find the babel plugin, which is definitely installed. It's something with the path.

If I copy that `xx.js` into the `resources/js`and then require it in `app.js`, no problem.

I've used `mix.webpackConfig` to add the module path `vendor/xxxx/assets/js`, I've used alisas to set `'xx$': path.resolve(__dirname,"vendor/xxxx/assets/js/xx.js"`, and tried to mess around with the babel options, both in .babelrc & the webpackConfig option object.

The one version of the final webpack config is below - believe me, I've played with many variants, I know this isn't the one right one, but nothing has worked to import/require/transpile any file outside of either node_modules (vue) or /resources/js (app.js, which can also require other files within that directory).  Any ideas would be great!

`{ context: 'C:\\www\\Laravels\\lsbb-5-3\\laravel',
  entry: 
   { '/mixed/js/es6': 
      [ 'C:\\www\\Laravels\\lsbb-5-3\\laravel\\resources\\js\\app.js',
        'C:\\www\\Laravels\\lsbb-5-3\\laravel\\vendor\\xxxx\\js\\xx.js' ] },
  output: 
   { path: 'C:\\www\\Laravels\\lsbb-5-3\\laravel\\public',
     filename: '[name].js',
     chunkFilename: '[name].js',
     publicPath: '/' },
  module: 
   { rules: 
      [ { test: /\.html$/, loaders: [ 'html-loader' ] },
        { test: /(\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$|^((?!font).)*\.svg$)/,
          loaders: 
           [ { loader: 'file-loader',
               options: { name: [Function: name], publicPath: '/' } },
             { loader: 'img-loader',
               options: { enabled: true, gifsicle: {}, mozjpeg: {}, optipng: {}, svgo: {} } } ] },
        { test: /(\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|otf)$|font.*\.svg$)/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: [Function: name], publicPath: '/' } },
        { test: /\.(cur|ani)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]', publicPath: '/' } },
        { test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: 
           [ { loader: 'babel-loader',
               options: 
                { cacheDirectory: true,
                  presets: 
                   [ [ 'env',
                       { modules: false,
                         targets: { browsers: [ '> 2%' ], uglify: true } } ] ],
                  plugins: 
                   [ 'transform-object-rest-spread',
                     [ 'transform-runtime', { polyfill: false, helpers: false } ],
                     [ 'transform-object-rest-spread' ] ] } } ] },
        { test: /\.css$/, loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
        { test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
          exclude: [],
          loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ] },
        { test: /\.less$/,
          exclude: [],
          loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ] } ] },
  plugins: 
   [ FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin {
       compilationSuccessInfo: {},
       onErrors: undefined,
       shouldClearConsole: true,
       formatters: [ [Function: format], [Function: format], [Function: format] ],
       transformers: 
        [ [Function: transform],
          [Function: transform],
          [Function: transform] ] },
     DefinePlugin {
       definitions: { 'process.env': { NODE_ENV: '"development"' } } },
     LoaderOptionsPlugin {
       options: 
        { minimize: false,
          options: 
           { context: 'C:\\www\\Laravels\\lsbb-5-3\\laravel\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\builder',
             output: { path: './' } },
          test: { test: [Function: test] } } },
     ManifestPlugin {},
     CustomTasksPlugin {},
     BuildCallbackPlugin { callback: [Function] },
     { options: 
        { title: 'Laravel Mix',
          alwaysNotify: true,
          hint: undefined,
          contentImage: 'C:\\www\\Laravels\\lsbb-5-3\\laravel\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\icons\\laravel.png' },
       lastBuildSucceeded: false,
       isFirstBuild: true } ],
  stats: 
   { hash: false,
     version: false,
     timings: false,
     children: false,
     errorDetails: false,
     chunks: false,
     modules: false,
     reasons: false,
     source: false,
     publicPath: false },
  performance: { hints: false },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  devServer: 
   { headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
     contentBase: 'C:\\www\\Laravels\\lsbb-5-3\\laravel\\public',
     historyApiFallback: true,
     noInfo: true,
     compress: true,
     quiet: true },
  resolve: 
   { extensions: [ '*', '.js', '.jsx', '.vue' ],
     alias:
      { 'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
        'xx$': 'vendor/xxxx/js/xx.js',
     modules:
      [ 'node_modules',
        'vendor/xxxx/js' ] } }`

Comment: Example for sweetalert `import swal from 'sweetalert2';`, example for `lodash.tonumber` `import toNumber from 'lodash.tonumber';`

Comment: Yes, but those are usually within `node_modules` - I have no problem with that. My issue is "requireing" something from outside that directory.  Maybe the issue is to use the "import" syntax rather than "require"?

Comment: Just use relative path, `../../somefile.js`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that - webpack finds the file no problem, runs babel on it to transpile, but it's babel that can't find its own plugin: `Unknown plugin "transform-object-rest-spread" specified` - but if the file to transpile is in node_modules, babel *DOES* find that plugin - which is also in node_modules, by the way...

Answer (score 1):

AHH! After days & nights, I finally figured it out!  The files in question are kind of like a library that I use in several projects, so I just symlink the directory into the project. I've been doing that for YEARS without problems with all kinds of build & project tools, so I didn't give it a thought.

BUT it turns out that Babel (or Babel in WebPack) breaks when it tries to follow symlinks!

So I can't say I found a solution, but I found a suitable work-around. The first step of my build process I just copy the files from the source directory into the project directory. Thats disgusting but actually works fine for my purposes - which is to just edit the library in a single location so I don't wind up with different versions. So I can just edit the source & build & voila!

If you have this problem and want to do it right, there are supposed to be additional plugins that help babel resolve these path issues but once I figured out what the problem was, I couldn't be bothered. Good luck to anyone else!

Answer (score 0):

The solution as found over on [Github](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1327) is to add this to your mix file:

```
mix.webpackConfig({ resolve: { symlinks: false } })
```